# include_once working but USE keyword not working in php

Tags: php

I have ClsMapping class. When I use

```
include_once('Folder/ClsMapping.php');
```

it worked, but when I use

```
use Folder/ClsMapping 
$obj = new ClsMapping();
$obj->a();
```

it is not working. I have defined namespace in ClsMapping.php file too
in ClsMapping.php

```
namespace Folder;
class ClsMapping{
   function a(){
   }
}
```

How could I get it worked? Any help would be great.

Error

```
Fatal error: Class 'ClsMapping' not found in E:\xampp\htdocs\ppm2.0\elastic\ClsSearchElastic.php on line 247
```

Comment: The case of 'folder' isnt the same. Upper or lower case? Also show how you defined the name space in ClsMapping file

Comment: what does "not working" actually mean?

Comment: @Akintunde that's same. that was my typing mistake.

Comment: @rtfm 'USE' keyword not working. Not allowing me to call function of that class

Comment: what error you are getting and give more code example, how you call and how you define ?

Comment: @user2486 plz see question

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I guess the problem that in "ClsMapping.php", there is no namespace, or the existing namespace is wrong.

To be sure, go to your class "ClsMapping.php", and just after the php tag, write your namespace (for example "namespace Folder;").

After that, you can make "use Folder/ClsMapping" without problems.

Comment: Can you please paste here your code for ClsMapping.php and the file where you are using "use".

Comment: Also the path for ClsMapping.php

Comment: try plz to start your file with <?php instead of <? because maybe your environment doesn't support open tags.
also after the use try to add ";"

Answer (score 0):

use doesn't include anything. It just imports the specified namespace (or class) to the current scope

[read this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php)

The use operator is not to be confused with autoloading. A class is autoloaded (negating the need for include) by registering an autoloader (e.g. with spl_autoload_register). You might want to read PSR-4 to see a suitable autoloader implementation.